# Wing radius formula

Tags: geometry

[image: wing Radius]

I need a formula to figure the radius of my wing top I'm building. I want a one inch drop on each end of my wing, 24 inches in on center line, and drop to 23 inches on  each end then square of each end for the end plate as shown. This is way more than that my part is 24 height 57.250 long C/L 28.625

I need to figure the Radius that will let it change 1 inch at each end point at the 28.625

Comment: Most of the people here might not know all of the terms you're using.  Making provide a better diagram pointing out exactly what you want or define all the terms you're using.